# variable equals constant in Java

Tags: java

I'm building a guessing game with Strings. The concept is pretty simple. I have a limited number of tries defined by a Java constant(C_Max_Trials = 10) and when the number of guesses reaches this constant the app should exit. The only thing is that I have to use this constant, this being part of my university assignment.

My problem is that Java won't consider my statements:

```
if (nrOfGuesses == C_Max_Trials) {
           System.out.println("Sorry you are out of tries");
           System.exit(0);"
```

If I put

```
nrOfGuesses == 0
```

it will work just fine. If I let

```
nrOfGuesses == C_Max_Trials
```

then it will not stop at 10 guesses and it will move on to guesses no -1,-2,-3.... continuing with the loop.

I'm attaching my code below. Also if you have any other feedback regarding the code it would be appreciated. I'm just starting with coding.

Thanks !

My code is:

```
    public class Assignment4 {
    public static final int C_Max_Trials = 10; 
    //Start Game

    String correctName = "X";
    boolean finished = false;
    int nrOfGuesses=10;

    while (!finished) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Please guess the name: "); 
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (name.equals(correctName))
    {
        finished = true;
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have guessed the name in "
                + nrOfGuesses+ " tries!");
        System.exit(0);

    }
       --nrOfGuesses;
       if (nrOfGuesses == C_Max_Trials) {
           System.out.println("Sorry you are out of tries");
           System.exit(0);
       }

           System.out.println("Sorry, you haven't guessed the name. You have "+
                nrOfGuesses + " left. Please try again:");

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're omitting some things here. What are you leaving out?

Comment: A post with a class called Assignment4 should definitely be tagged as homework.

Answer (score 3):

If `nrOfGuesses` *starts* at 10 and then only gets decremented... how do you expected it to be *equal* to 10? (Barring overflow...)

You need to decide whether `nrOfGuesses` is meant to be:

- The number of guesses *left*: start it at the constant, decrement it on each step, and compare with 0
- The number of guesses you've *had*: start it at 0, increment it, and compare with the constant

Answer (score 2):

You're counting *down* (`--nrOfGuesses`) from 10.

Count *up* (`nrOfGuesses++`) from `0` to `C_Max_Trials` or count down from `C_Max_Trials` instead of the hardcoded `10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final int C_Max_Trials = 10;
//...
--nrOfGuesses;
```

You start trials at 10 and go down, so it's never equal to max trials. Try setting max trials to 0 or start trials at 0 and make it go up.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to want to force termination when number of guesses reaches the maximum number of guesses, but you start at 10 guesses and decrement in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile. And `C_Max_Trials` is initialized to 10, not 0. So obviously, it will not stop at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is backwards; you're *decrementing* `nrOfGuesses` and then comparing it with the *maximum* amount of guesses that you're allowed.  In this case, you should either be *incrementing* `nrOfGuesses` or comparing it to zero and setting it to `C_Max_Trials` at the start.

If I were you, I'd opt for incrementing `nrOfGuesses` and comparing it to `C_Max_Trials`, since that makes `nrOfGuesses` hold a value that makes sense to its name (it holds the number of guesses).  Otherwise, you'd be holding the number of guesses *remaining* with that variable, and then it should be renamed to `guessesRemaining` or something like that.

Certainly, if you wish to use `nrOfGuesses` as you do in the part where you inform the user how many tries (s)he took to correctly guess, then it should be incremented each loop, not decremented.